# How to apply binding data in ng-repeat with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i user `ng-repeat` to render a list:

```
 $scope.mockData={
    agentItems:[{
        url:"bjstdmngbgr02.thoughtworks.com",
        resource:"ubuntu,firefox3,core-duo"
    },{
        url:"bjstdmngbgr03.thoughtworks.com",
        resource:"ubuntu,firefox3,core-duo"
    },{
        url:"bjstdmngbgr04.thoughtworks.com",
        resource:"ubuntu,firefox3,core-duo"
    },{
        url:"bjstdmngbgr05.thoughtworks.com",
        path:"/var/lib/cruise-agent",
    }]};
```

i need to list all agentItems and then list all resource in every agentItems, my html code like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="agentItem in mockData.agentItems" class="agentItem border-small">
                                <div class="agentImage"></div>
                                <div>
                                    <span>{{agentItem.url}}                                 </div>
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#" ng-click="openAddedResModel()">Specify a resource</a>
                                    <span class="separator"></span>
                                    <div>
                                        Resource:
                                        <span ng-repeat="resource in agentItem.resource.split(',')">
                                            {{resource}}<button ng-click="removeResource($index,agentItem.resource)">X</button>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

you see, the original resource is a string and i convert it to array in order to remove the one i click the 'x' button.
my removeReource function is this :

```
$scope.removeResource=function(index,totalResource){
        var arrTr=totalResource.split(',')
        arrTr.splice(index,1);
        console.log(totalResource);
        $scope.$apply(function(){
               totalResource=arrTr.join(',');
            });
    }
```

i want to use `$apply`, it show me an error: `$apply already in progress`.
How could i notify agentItems.resource changed so that angular can update my list in UI?

Answer (score 0):

An apply is or digest is already on going, so there is no need to use apply again.

```
    $scope.removeResource=function(index,totalResource){
        var arrTr=totalResource.split(',')
        arrTr.splice(index,1);
        console.log(totalResource);
        totalResource=arrTr.join(',');
    }
```

Apply is mostly used outside of the angular world, fx. coming back from a jquery event in a directive, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

As Andre suggested, you don't need to call $apply since ng-click will trigger a diggest loop that will cause the watches to re-evaluate hence it will find that the agentItem.resource has changed.

Answer (score 0):

thank @André Snede Hansen and @Wawy.

I have got my problem. javascript will make a copy for my paremeter so it won't trigger the data change.
i changed my code to this to fix that.

```
<span ng-repeat="resource in agentItem.resource.split(',')">
{{resource}}<button ng-click="removeResource($index,agentItem)">X</button>
</span>
```

and my removeResource method to:

```
$scope.removeResource=function(index,agentItem){
        var arrTr=agentItem.resource.split(',')
        arrTr.splice(index,1);
        agentItem.resource=arrTr.join(',');;
    }
```